# Why does angularFire $add(user) method adds the same record twice ? How to keep firebase records unique?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I dont want angularFire to keep adding duplicate records, how can I make it to only add the user once and if user data already has been added to the database do not add the same user again.

I have a button like that:

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success" href="#" ng-hide="auth.user" ng-click="auth.$login('persona')"><span><i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Login with <strong>Persona</strong></a>
```

and my controller has:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://mybase.firebaseio.com/");
                        $scope.auth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(ref);

var users = new Firebase("https://mybase.firebaseio.com/users");
                        $scope.uData = $firebase(users);

$scope.auth.$login('persona').then(function(user){

                             var usersArray = orderByPriorityFilter($scope.uData);

                             if (_.contains((_.pluck(usersArray, 'uid')),user.uid) == false){$scope.uData.$add(user)}


                         });
```

login partial and partial that user gets redirected to after he/she logins have separate controllers and if I try to add user data to database in the login controller (before user gets redirected) then same user is added 4 times in the database instead of 2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$add` method should only be used to create (and append) new records with a chronologically incremental ID. If you want to overwrite (or create if a record isn't already present), you can use the $save or $set method.

```
$scope.auth.$login('persona').then(function(user){
  var usersArray = orderByPriorityFilter($scope.uData);
  if (_.contains((_.pluck(usersArray, 'uid')),user.uid) == false){
    $scope.uData.$child(user.uid).$set(user);
  }
});
```